# How to modify view.alphaValue at runtime and take effect

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

I modified the alphaValue at runtime but has not any effect , what is the problem. how to modify the alphaValue at runntime ?

I want to adjust the alphaValue of view  at runtime

Xcode 10.2.1   Swift 4.2

```swift
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  macosappalphaValuetest
//
//  Created by miller on 2019/7/25.
//  Copyright © 2019 miller. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBAction func btnclick1(_ sender: Any) {
       self.view.alphaValue = 0.8

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        view.window?.isOpaque = false
        view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
        self.view.alphaValue = 0.4
        }

    }
```

Comment: It is `view.alpha` not `view.alphaValue`. Your question is unclear, Could you add more detail to it? What is the issue and expected result ?

Comment: tested your code everything works, not alphaValue but alpha

Comment: alphpValue actually , here is xcode 10.2.1 swift 4.2 above

Comment: @baileymiller2017 Okay, Consider it as `alphaValue`, but what is issue? Is view not transparent after setting this? Add screen capture of your view and include the expected result in your code.

Comment: the btnclick1 action take no effect，the window still seems to be t he same alpha value transparent  , you can try it at xcode

Comment: i want to modify the alphavalue to be higher and make the windows to be opaque almost.

Comment: @baileymiller2017 You should mention that this is a cocoa (Mac) application. Edit your question and add a tag for mac app.

Comment: ok  , i add the cocoa tag  then

Comment: @baileymiller2017 Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `NSViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` method your view's window is probably `nil`. You can check it by printing `print(view.window)`. So you need to get the correct instance of your window. See below method:

```
func validWindow() -> NSWindow? {
    var window = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow
    if (window == nil) {
        window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first
    }
    return window
}
```

And just write below code to make your window transparent:

```
guard let window = self.validWindow() else { return }
window.alphaValue = 0.5
```

It works well for me.

**Output:**

[image]

**Increasing and Decreasing alpha value recursively:**

```
func decreaseAlpha(_ window: NSWindow) {
    let alpha = window.alphaValue - 0.1
    if alpha < 0.0 {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1) {
            self.increaseAlpha(window)
        }
        return
    }

    window.alphaValue = alpha
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1) {
        self.decreaseAlpha(window)
    }
}

func increaseAlpha(_ window: NSWindow) {
    let alpha = window.alphaValue + 0.1
    if alpha > 1.0 {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1) {
            self.decreaseAlpha(window)
        }
        return
    }

    window.alphaValue = alpha
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1) {
        self.increaseAlpha(window)
    }
}
```

And write this in `viewDidLoad:` method:

```
guard let window = self.validWindow() else { return }
decreaseAlpha(window)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: fail to change the alphaValue still 
```
 class ViewController: NSViewController {
    func validWindow() -> NSWindow? {
        var window = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow
        if (window == nil) {
            window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first
        }
        return window
    }
    @IBAction func btnclick1(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let window = self.validWindow() else { return }
        window.alphaValue = 0.9
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I wrote this code in `viewDidLoad:` method and it changes the alpha value to 0.5 (half transparent). What do you expect? Try with 0.4 or 0.5 ?

Comment: I just want to change the alphaValue which makes the windows could be transparent or opaque little by little  with the button click action.

Comment: @baileymiller2017 The attached screenshot is not what you're looking for?

Comment: No , I had done that also . for now , I want to make it adjustable, could be change little by little under control.   why don't you catch my meanings . sorry.

Comment: `adjustable` You mean changing it by slider? Or after a specific time difference? Or every time you click on button it should be lighter? Or with animation from last `alphaValue` to `newValue`? I'm still not getting your point.

Comment: slider or button is ok ，and they should be the same mechanism

Comment: What happen if you write `window.alphaValue = window.alphaValue - 0.1` on your button click?

Comment: nothing happens  , the windows remain still the same  ,  i realize i  got the wrong way from viewcontroller , so i ask the question here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196978/discussion-between-thetiger-and-baileymiller2017).

Comment: sorry  ,  i  cannot launch chat mode and i am checking

Comment: @baileymiller2017 Check the answer now.

Comment: I was afraid before updating my answer. But glad it was that what you needed. (y)

Answer (score -1):

`alphaValue` is the Objective-C version of `alpha`. Applying `alpha` on the viewController view will make it slightly transparent and possible show the viewController that is beneath it if there is one. If there are no 
view controllers beneath it, it will lean towards a darker background as the default background is black.

Comment: This is not true. This is `alpha` in `Objective-C` too.

Comment: Please don't call a view a view controller.